# Show that there is no analytic bijection from the unit disc to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Show that there is no analytic bijection from the unit disc to $\mathbb{C}$.

I am quite unsure how to proceed here. I know for a fact that there is no analytic function from $\mathbb{C}$ to the open disc by Louvilles theorem.

Suppose that $f$ is ideed an analytic bijection from the unit disc to $\mathbb{C}$. Then consider the map $g(z)=f(\frac{1}{z})$. Now $g$ is an analytic bijective function from $\mathbb{C}/\{0\}$ to $\mathbb{C}$. Can this be extended to a proof?

Comment: Can it happen that the inverse is not analytic?

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen Are you saying that a bijective analytic map has an analytic inverse?

Comment: Hi @Aloysius, it's a special property of holomorphic functions that a bijective holomorphic function admits a holomorphic inverse (an analogous statement is not true for real analytic functions as $f(x)=x^3$ shows). The key fact needed is that an injective holomorphic function must have non-vanishing derivative. Are you aware of this?

Comment: @ Amitesh Datta No I have not encountered this result. Where can I learn more about this?

Comment: I guess most complex analysis textbooks should contain this fact. However, here is a proof sketch ($\phi$ is holomorphic near $0$ and WLOG $\phi(0)=0$): if $\phi'(0)\neq 0$, then $\phi$ admits an analytic inverse near $0$; otherwise, $\phi$ has a zero of order $n>1$ at $0$ and $\phi(z)=z^n\psi(z)$ for some $\psi$ which does not vanish near $0$. Locally, $\psi$ thus has an $n$th root (say, $\eta$) so we can write $\phi(z)=(z\eta(z))^n$ which is clearly not injective (it is $n$-to-$1$). I've possibly used something non-trivial in this proof, so let me know if I should elaborate.

Comment: @Amitesh Datta  I understand how it is locally invertible with the inverse being analytic. How does this extend to the entire unit ball?

Comment: Hi @Aloysius, if I understand your question correctly: "set-theoretically", the map admits an inverse because it is bijective. Now, we know that locally this inverse map is holomorphic, so it must therefore be (globally) holomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

Denote unit disc as $\mathbb{D}$.

If there exists an analytical $\space f: \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{D}$, then $f$ is a bounded entire function, and therefore by [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(complex_analysis)), $\space f$ is constant, so it cannot be a bijection.

Comment: But the question asks for $f\colon\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: It asks about "bijection", which is two way one-to-one mapping. So we only need to invalidate one side to prove it does not exist.

Comment: Then you need to justify that $f^{-1}$ is analytic. This has been done in the comments to the question,

Comment: @JuliánAguirre, Sorry I didn't get that. Why do I need to show $f^{-1}$ is analytical? If I can reach contradiction by assuming $f$ analytical, isn't it enough?

Comment: You want to apply Liuoville's theorem to $f^{-1}$.

Comment: But the $f$ I defined here is $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{D}$, and I am applying Liuoville on this $f$, so I just need to use the facts: 1) it is analytical; 2) it is bounded (because the unit disc.

Comment: The questionn asks if $f\colon\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}$ exists. You prove that it does not applying Liouville's theorem to $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should know the following proposition:

> If $f$ is analytic injection on a region $\Omega$, then its inverse function $f^{-1}:f(\Omega)\to\Omega$ is also injective and analytic.

(For a complete proof, see any book on complex analysis. Here is one possible outline:
[1] Show that $f'(z)\ne0$ for all $z\in\Omega$.
[2] Show that $f^{-1}$ is analytic, and $(f^{-1})'(w_0)=1/f'(z_0)$, where $w_0=f(z_0)$.)

Now, if there is an analytic bijection $f$ from the unit disk $U$ to $\mathbb{C}$, $f^{-1}$ is an analytic bijection from $\mathbb{C}$ to $U$. You have known it is impossible.